# What happens to a dynamic array (on the heap) within a struct on the stack?

Tags: c++

My concern is whether or not the array should be deallocated. Here is an example:

```
typedef struct
{
    int *values;
    int length;
} a_struct;

void foo()
{
    a_struct myStruct;
    myStruct.values = new int[NUM];  

    delete[] myStruct.values; // Is this needed?
    return;  
}
```

My understanding is that myStruct (which is on the stack) will get deleted automatically upon the "return" statement. Does it delete "values" as well?

Comment: I dunno - where is dtor?

Comment: @MartinJames Apparently, the struct has no explicit destructor.

Answer (score 4):

It does deallocate *the pointer* `values`, but ***not what it points to*** - after all, what does `a_struct` know about what you assigned to that pointer? Maybe it's a pointer to stuff allocated on the stack, or to an array shared with another `struct`.

So, yes, you need to manually deallocate it (although in modern C++ often "smart pointers" are used to manage memory).

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't, you should delete it manually. `myStruct` going out of scope (and thus the `myStruct.values` member, i. e. *the pointer* being invalidated) has nothing to do with the dynamically allocated memory. **The golden rule: if you call `new[]`, always `delete[]`** (same for `new` and `delete`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is needed, the struct only stores the address of the array.
These days people would just store a std::vector<> (or if you just want an owning pointer to something a std::unique_ptr<>).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing gets 'deleted'. The stack is popped. Period. As the struct doesn't have a destructor, nothing else happens.